# Prevent modal dialog from closing after saving an item.

Tags: html

Prevent modal dialog from closing after saving an item. For example, when editing an item in a modal dialog, after the user saves the item, I would like for the item to remain open. Currently, the user edits and item and upon save the dialog box closes and the page refreshes. The user then will have to go back to the location he/she was working in. Please assist. I would prefer html but open to plenty suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom Edit form.  This will open up the ListViewWebPart code for you  in SPD so you can look into the save and cancel actions on the form.  You can then add your own custom save button and hide the default one.  You should be able to set the redirect to go where you like instead of back to the list.

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={home.aspx}')}" />
```